# How to limit kept text messages in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, sms

I'm not an iPhone user, but help support them at work.

We have a user who has a large amount of SMS messages for having the same iPhone for quite a few years. He's trying to delete old SMS messages.

On my Android (Galaxy S3), I'm able to set a Text message limit: 200 messages per conversation, so only the most recent 200 messages are kept for each conversation.

Is there something similar for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in iOS 8 you can set a limit to the **time period** of the messages. So, not an actual amount - like the 200 messages on your Android - but you can limit it through Settings > Messages > Keep Messages menu option where you'll see the following flavors:

- Forever
- 1 Year
- 30 Days